# How to convert a Lead into a contact using salesforce IOS mobile

Tags: lead-conversion, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I am builiding an IOS mobile app ( native app ) which creates a Lead using the salesforce mobile SDK (IOS). I could not find an API to convert a lead to a contact like how you can do in Apex.
    Any one has any ideas on how to do this. Eventually i want to convert a Lead to a contact and create an task from the mobile app itself.
    Thanks in advance.

~Vasu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a lead through the SOAP API. Check out [ZKSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce), an Objective-C wrapper around the SOAP API. I contributed some [async block methods](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce/blob/master/zkSforce/zkSforceClient%2BzkAsyncQuery.h) that make this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Write this code inside of leadConvert Func**

```
    let leadConvertObj = ZKLeadConvert()
    leadConvertObj.leadId = leadId;
    leadConvertObj.convertedStatus = leadStatus;
    leadConvertObj.doNotCreateOpportunity = checkButton
    if !checkButton {
        leadConvertObj.opportunityName = self.opporchunityText.text
    }
    if let _ = accointInfo {
        leadConvertObj.accountId = accointInfo!["Id"] as? String
    }


    client?.performConvertLead([leadConvertObj], failBlock: { exp in
        let button2Alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "Lead Status Picklist Values is not Converted",
            delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        button2Alert.show()
                    }, completeBlock: { success in
            print(success)

            let result = success.last as? ZKLeadConvertResult
            print(result?.accountId )
            print(result?.contactId )
            print(result?.opportunityId )
            print(result?.leadId )
            print(result?.success)
```